# Same Origin Policy limitation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, server-side

So you can't make a request to another domain under the same origin policy. But does that apply to code you running inside the Chrome JS console with the page of that domain opened? And does that apply to a backend server app making a request to the other domain?

Comment: you can make a request under the same origin policy if the receiving server allows the policy to be accessed in such a way

Comment: why don't you test it? open up the google homepage, then open the console and basically do `$.get('http://google.com')`

Answer (score 1):

**Question1: Chrome**

When you run code inside Chrome JS console, you are running code in the context of a given page and you inherit the same security sandbox that the page has. All web pages are subject to CORS restrictions (cross origin resource sharing).

As a side note, cross origin request are allowed if the API you are calling explicitely allows them (which is implemented server side by setting some HTTP headers), or if you use another legacy cross origin *technique* (hacks) like JSONP.

**Question 2: Server side**

CORS is a browser thing, to protect web users against malicious JS acting on their behalf (for example, to reconfigure their home router), there is no such thing server side.

Comment: The chrome answer is pretty vague, so can do or no can do?

Comment: You cannot do cross origin request if the API you call does not allow it when executing javascript from a webpage, either from the console, or from loaded scripts.

Comment: My question said " with the page of that domain opened," how is that then?

Comment: That does not change a thing. If I have a tab open on my bank account, and another on the new york times, the new york times cannot execute javascript to call my bank's API. But of course you can call your bank's API with chrome's console *from the bank's tab*.

Comment: i thought the question was pretty clear "the page of that domain opened" means bank's page opened in a tab, making request to the bank's domain in that same tab, that is a can do right?

Comment: Yes you can, because it is not a cross-origin request, it is a same origin request.